# upload image to server from iOS

Tags: php, objective-c, file-upload, image-uploading

Using the following code I've managed to upload a **jpg** named **TESTTEST** to my server from my iOS app

```
- (void)saveImageToServer {
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_profileImage, 90);
    //NSString *urlString = @"URL 1/upload.php";
    NSString *urlString = @"URL 2 /upload.php";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"_187934598797439873422234";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/536.26.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.1 Safari/536.26.14" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    [request setValue:@"http://google.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Origin"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", @"TESTTEST"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
}
```

---

This was a while ago and I remembered setting the rights of that folder to `777`. Now I'm using the same code to upload the image to another domain (URL 2) using the same php file but that just failed. I've set the right of that folder to `777` too. Also I've tested this obj-c and php code on the first domain and that works.

Can somebody tell me where to start looking for a problem? It must be something server related because it works fine on the first URL. Is there a way I can print something in PHP to help me debug?

Here is my php file. It's really basic and I just want that image on the server for testing purposes:

```php
<?php
    //$target_path "./uploads/profile_image/"
    $target_path = "./";  // Testing

    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']);  

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {  
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['picture']['name'])." has been uploaded";  
    } else{  
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";  
    } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do two things:

1. add some more `echo`es to your php files to inspect $_GET/$_POST/$_FILES to see if everything is ok; also use `realpath` to see what your `target_path` resolves to;
2. use that `NSError` argument to `sendSynchronousRequest` to see what happens to the request client-side:

   ```
        NSError* error = nil;
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
   ```

Comment: Thanks Ill try that asap. Right now I'm looking into the new NSURLSession and think I'm going to convert all my NSURLConnections to Sessions.

Comment: realpath resolves to the correct folder and NSError is null. Still have no idea where to look